# The Spark project runs normally locally, but when I submit the cluster, it reports a null pointer exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, closures, cluster-computing

I set multiple global variables outside the function (def) of the object file and initialize them to null, then assign and update them in one of the functions, and call these global variables in another function, which makes me get Variables are always null. I'm guessing it might be a closure issue, how can I fix it?

```
object probA {

  // NON-FLUENT
  var COURSES_PER_SEMESTER: Int = 0
  var COURSE_COST: Double = 0
  var COURSE_RETAKE_COST: Double = 0
  var PROGRAM_INCOMPLETE_PENALTY: Double = 0
  var PREREQ: List[Array[String]] = null
  var PRIOR_PROB_PASS_NO_PREREQ: mutable.Map[String, Double] = null
  
  
  def A{}
  def B: Unit ={
    COURSES_PER_SEMESTER = 5
        ...
  }
}
```

I checked a lot of information and thought it might be a closure problem, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of your problem and that we could reproduce?